# In PHP, how to get UTC date for calendars that include Day Light Savings (DLS)

Tags: php, datetime, dst

I'm not sure if the `gmdate()` function in PHP captures the Day Light Savings reality of the world. For example this code:

```
<?php 

echo "<pre>";

echo "Current timezone: ", date_default_timezone_get(), "\n"; 
$future_date = 'Nov 03, 2019  03:30 PM EDT';
$future_UTC  = gmdate('M d, Y  h:i A T', strtotime($future_date));

echo "
New York Date: $future_date 
GMT/UTC time:  $future_UTC
"; 

?>
```

Prints out this:

```
Current timezone: UTC

  New York Date: Nov 03, 2019  03:30 PM EDT 
  GMT/UTC time:  Nov 03, 2019  07:30 PM GMT
```

This is technically incorrect, because on Nov 3 at 2pm, the DLS will switch and the time in GMT/UTC will actually be **08:30 PM**, instead of the erroneous  *07:30 PM* that PHP is showing (based on today's DLS).

Is there any way to automatically get the right time for future dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many errors here, starting with the title of your question:

> how to get UTC date for calendars that include Day Light Savings (DLS)

UTC is well-defined, and has no daylight savings time.  If you're in a different timezone, and in a locality that has daylight savings time, then you're not in UTC anymore.  So, the question is nonsensical to begin with.

```
$future_date = 'Nov 03, 2019  03:30 PM EDT';
```

`EDT` means "Eastern Daylight Time", so in this case you're forcing a particular interpretation, regardless of date.  You'll note that if you change it to `EST` (Eastern Standard Time), you'll get a different result.

You probably want `America/New_York` instead of `EDT`.  See also:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

> This is technically incorrect, because on Nov 3 at 2pm, the DLS will switch

No.  2:00 AM.

> Is there any way to automatically get the right time for future dates?

Stop feeding PHP broken data and ambiguously formatted dates.  We have date/time standards for a reason, such as ISO8601.  Date/time is a complicated thing.  Computers can't read minds, and don't know what you intended when you gave it the wrong date for a specific type of timezone with daylight savings time.

Comment: Thanks Brad. The `EST` suggestion is very helpful. That's what I needed. Much appreciate the insight despite the reprimanding tone :)

Comment: @KhomNazid Ha, sorry, I get cranky when people blame the system for things, when it's definitely not the system's fault.  Anyway, glad you find this helpful!  You might really consider though `America/New_York` instead so that PHP will figure this out for you.  This is particularly important if you want your application to stay in-line with future updates.

Comment: Maybe `America/Toronto` then?  Strange that it didn't work for you... I had tested it on a REPL and it was fine, so maybe it was a PHP version difference?

Comment: Thanks @Brad, I tried `Canada/Toronto`, and that produces different diverse results for some reason on my Mac with PHP 5.6 and on our Redhat server with 7.3. `EST` was the right nudge, a lot of online examples use `EDT`, so I got hoodwinked. Should have tried `EST` to begin with.